# How to prevent enter key from making new line during resharper intellisense completion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, intellisense

I have a lot of experience as an Intellij developer where the enter key will always insert the first auto-complete suggestion. In visual studio with resharper however, the enter key will create a new line instead of inserting the first intellisense suggestion. Can anyone suggest a way to allow the enter key to replicate the Intellij behavior? I know pressing the tab key behaves as expected by my muscle memory keeps pressing enter without me thinking about it.

Comment: Did you use the Resharper Intellisense or Visual Studio Intellisense in your project? If you use Visual Studio Intellisense for a c# project, you can try to disable this behavior---choose `Never add new line on enter`  by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Text Editor`-->`C#`-->`Intellisense`-->`Enter Key Behavior`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone suggest a way to allow the enter key to replicate the
>   Intellij behavior? I know pressing the tab key behaves as expected by
>   my muscle memory keeps pressing enter without me thinking about it.

In your side, you have installed Resharper, so you have two ways to use Intellisense: **Visual Studio Intellisense** which is the default way for Visual Studio, **Resharper Intellisense**.

**1)** If you use **Visual Studio Intellisense**(make sure you choose `Visual Studio` by the top menu `ReSharper`-->Options-->`Environment`-->`Intellisense`-->`General`) and face this issue, please try this:

- choose `Never add new line on enter` by `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Text Editor`-->`C#`(please choose the corresponding development language)-->`Intellisense`-->`Enter Key Behavior`.

**2)** If you use **Resharper Intellisense**(make sure you choose `Resharper` by the top menu `ReSharper`-->Options-->`Environment`-->`Intellisense`-->`General`),  you will not face this issue.

**Note**: if you face this issue in **Resharper Intellisense**, l think it is the issue about some changes in Resharper Option.You can try to reset Resharper settings by `Resharper`-->`Manage Options`-->`Reset all settings`.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the differences between Visual Studio Intellisense and Resharper Intellisense? I used the first one, as it's default and got the "Enter" behaviour working correctly, but I have no idea what the difference is between those two.

Comment: Using Resharper IntelliSense didn't work for me, and unfortunately resetting all settings didn't either. :(

Comment: Not working with Resharper IntelliSense

Comment: Regarding the VS Intellisense, unfortunately, the "Enter Key Behavior" seems to only apply after you have explicitly selected the Intellisense proposal you want to use (by pressing the arrow keys at least once). However, it does not facilitate selecting the first proposal directly by just pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update for the previously posted answer as I noticed the location has changed slightly as of now. I found this option (using **Visual Studio Intellisense**) under:

`Tools menu` > `Text Editor` > `C/C++` (or whatever language you are using) > `Advanced` > `IntelliSense` section > set `Member List Commit Aggressive` to **True**.

Comment: The `Member List Commit Aggressive` option only seems to appear in the `C/C++` language settings.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it was driving me crazy. Under Visual Studio 2022 using ReSharper 2023.1.4 I could achieve the desired behaviour here:

*Extensions* -> *ReSharper* -> *Options...* -> *Environment* -> *IntelliSense* -> *Autopopup*

And in that menu, change the *"Autopopup Behavior"* to *"Display and preselect"* for **everything**. Apparently, *"Display but do not preselect"* disables the autocomplete on the enter-key.

Hope this helps.